# Incorrect indication for column store index in execution plan SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I have SQL Server 2012 SP1 developer edition. I have the test DB with single table in it and has 10M rows and about 150 column (about 133 columns are `numeric` and rest are `NVARCHAR`)

I am experimenting with column store index performance and comparing it with the no index scenario.

What I see is the DB in which I have create column store index, when I look at the graphical execution plan it does not show me the icon for column store operation but instead regular index scan. Because I have only one index on that which is column store and no other non/clustered index I believe that index is getting used as column store.

So my question is is it something with my environment that the right icon is not showing up or I am missing anything else here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it used columnstore the node would show the right icon and also would be called "Columnstore Index Scan" instead of "Index Scan".

Could you check that you really do not have a regular non-clustered index on that table?
(Just refresh and expand the Indexes node under dbo.Test_PDMTable in the Object Explorer of SSMS)

I believe you will see the Cs_NcIdx_Test1 index there, which says in brackets: (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered).
The columnstore index should say (Non-Clustered, Columnstore) instead.

**UPDATE:**

> A possible reason of a wrong icon/label could be: using an older version of SSMS to connect to a newer version of SQL Server.

Comment: I do not have any other index except the Column Store index.

Comment: Maybe you are using 2008 or older version of SSMS connecting to your 2012 server?
This would behave exactly as you described.

Comment: this is it. yes, i was connecting via sql 2008r2 ssms. I will try using sql2012 ssms and see. hope it solves the issue. you can update your answer with the same comment and after verifying on 2012 ssms i will accept the answer.